# Serverless deploy error provisionning stack

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

When I try to deploy my application on AWS, I get the following error :

> An error occurred while provisioning your stack: HelloLambdaFunction -
>   Lambda was unable to configure your environment variables because the
>   environment variables you have provided contains reserved keys that
>   are currently not supported for modification. Reserved keys used in
>   this request: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

My AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are stored in env.yml and I access them using process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try removing those keys from the config and see what happens.

Comment: the error is telling you specifically that you CAN'T set those where you've set them.

Comment: Correct ! Before doing serverless deploy, I was setting up my env variables using export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX and export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX so I guess putting them into the env.yml would be to setting them twice. The error message therefore makes sens. Thank you.